# Is the inclusion of schwartz space on $L^{p}$ continous

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

I was wondering if the inclusion of the Schwartz space on the $L^{p}$ spaces was continous. I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802042/inclusion-of-schwartz-space-on-lp) question but it only says that there is an inclusion.

Can we prove that it is continous? *i.e.:* $\forall \left( \varphi_{n} \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, $\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, $\varphi_{n} \rightarrow \varphi \Rightarrow \| \varphi_{n} - \varphi \|_{p} \rightarrow 0$.

I am specially interested in the case of $p=2$ so a proof in this case will fit for me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Roughly speaking any time $X$ and $Y$ are complete topological vector spaces and $X\subset Y$  then the inclusion is continuous. There may be counterexamples, but finding one takes a little work. In practical terms the _proof_ that $X\subset Y$ is "always"  going to contain a proof of continuity - that certainly happens in this case.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that the *question* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802042/inclusion-of-schwartz-space-on-lp) only says there is an inclusion, but the *answer* actually writes down explicitly an inequality which on one side has the $L_p$ norm and on the other side has a quantity involving the semi-norms in ${\cal S}(\mathbb{R})$, which proves that the inclusion is indeed continuous with respect to the usual topologies on $L_p$ and ${\cal S}(\mathbb{R})$.