# Schwarz Space contained in L^p?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

How can one proof the inclusion of the Schwarz Space $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Here ([Inclusion of Schwartz space on $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802042/inclusion-of-schwartz-space-on-lp)) it is discussed for n=1, but i don't know how to extend this to $n>1$, since i don't know if $1/(1+|x|^2)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: You can use an even sharper bound based on the definition of the Schwartz space. Think about what the spherical measure is and how you need to account for it in conjunction with the $L^p$ norm. What decay rate do you need?

Comment: $(1+\|x\|^2)^{-N}$ is integrable on $\Bbb{R}^N$, and $(1+\|x\|^2)^N$ is in the seminorms defining $S(\Bbb{R}^N)$.

Comment: Ah thanks @JohnDoe, i got it!

Comment: @CameronWilliams what is the spherical measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: It's the $r^{n-1} \,dr\,d\Omega$ bit, specifically the $r^{n-1}$ part is the important part because it is easy to deal with. The $d\Omega$ integral is just the surface area of the sphere, so it is finite.